# How do I not let UIViews overlap when I create them by tapping?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, calendar

I am creating a calendar app, and I tap to create new events in a UIScrollView. Think of it like the apple calendar "day view" where you can create new events and view them in a list on a scroll view. Each event is a UIView with a TextField on it, and right now everything works but I'm not sure how to make it so the events don't overlap when I create them.

Is there a way to prevent UIViews from overlapping when I create them or move them? I only am moving them up or down, so I just need to keep them from overlapping on the y axis. Right now I tap to create them, but they can overlap. Is there a way to put them on the same plane or something so they can't be added on top of each other?

Comment: "Each event is a UIView"  We don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended you post your own code for us to understand the general direction you're heading towards. Otherwise, it could a wasted effort on both of our parts.

For example, you mentioned that "right now everything works", but I have no idea how you're moving the views in a vertical manner. I went ahead and subclassed the gesture recognizer so hopefully it fits the flow of your code.

```swift
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
    var v1: UIView!
    var v2: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.v1 = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 100), size: size))
        self.view.addSubview(self.v1)
        self.v1.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.v2 = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 300), size: size))
        self.view.addSubview(v2)
        self.view.addSubview(self.v2)
        self.v2.backgroundColor = .purple
        
        let verticalGesture = VerticalGesture(target: self, action: #selector(dragged))
        self.v2.addGestureRecognizer(verticalGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func dragged(_ sender: VerticalGesture) {
        
    }
}

class VerticalGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    private var touch: UITouch!
    private var currentView: UIView!
    private var currentSuperview: UIView!
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        guard let firstTouch = touches.first, let currentView = self.view, let currentSuperview = currentView.superview else { return }
        self.touch = firstTouch
        self.currentView = currentView
        self.currentSuperview = currentSuperview
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        var center = self.currentView.center
        let currentLocation = self.touch.location(in: self.currentSuperview)
        let previousLocation = self.touch.previousLocation(in: self.currentSuperview)
        let yTranslation = currentLocation.y - previousLocation.y
        center.y += yTranslation
        self.view!.center = center
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        for subview in self.currentSuperview.subviews {
            // this goes through all the sibling views including the non-calendar-event views i.e. calendar dates, calendar frame, etc
            // so make sure to sort those out
            if subview != self.currentView! && self.currentView!.frame.intersects(subview.frame) {
                var center = self.currentView.center
                let isHigher = subview.center.y >= center.y
                // isHigher >= 0 means the current view that you've selected is located higher
                // than the overlapping view below
                if isHigher {
                    center = CGPoint(x: subview.center.x, y: subview.center.y - self.currentView.bounds.height)
                    self.view!.center = center
                } else {
                    center = CGPoint(x: subview.center.x, y: subview.center.y + self.currentView.bounds.height)
                    self.view!.center = center
                }
            }
        }
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Depending on whether the calendar event you're dragging is on the upper side or the lower side of the overlapping view, it will move to adjacent to it. Feel free to add a transform animation to it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Sorry I wasn't very specific but you hit the nail on the head, perfect fix for my problem.  Thanks!